# How do I create an object in c# similar to powershell system.object?

Tags: c#, powershell, c#-4.0, custom-object

In Powershell, I can do the following with a list

```
$obj = New-Object System.Object    
foreach ($item in $list) {
       $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name fname -value $item.firstname
       $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name lname -value $item.lastname
    }

    $obj
```

and this will print out two columns with the first and last name.

In C#, i'm not sure how I can accomplish this. Do I need to create a custom class for each object? Or is there a way to do this dynamically in c# like in powershell?

The data i've got is in JSON. I can use JSON.net to iterate through the list of results but I'm not sure how to put them into an object such that

```
WriteObject(customObj);
```

will result in the same output as above.

By the way, this is all inside of a `PSCmdlet` class so output will always go to the console/cmd window.

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# you should operate on `PSObject` to achieve same result as your PowerShell code:

```
PSObject obj=new PSObject();
obj.Properties.Add(new PSNoteProperty(fname,item.firstname));
obj.Properties.Add(new PSNoteProperty(lname,item.lastname));
WriteObject(obj);
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to verify your answer. I was only just able to get back to the task. I followed your suggestion along with ArrayList to produce a nice table of objects that can be easily used by PowerShell. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Your best option would be to use [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). The code you gave would (probably) be equivalent to:

```cs
var obj = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var item in list)
    obj.Add(new { fname = item.firstname, lname = item.lastname });
//From here, use whatever output method you would like.
```

To access the members, use `obj[index].fname` to get the `fname` at `index`, `obj[index].lname` to get the `lname` at `index`, `obj.Select(item => item.fname)` to get an `IEnumerable<string>` of all `fname`s, and `obj.Select(item => item.lname)` to get an `IEnumerable<string>` of all `lname`s.